# spinbox and Scale changing each other's values in Tkinter

Tags: python, widget, tkinter

For my program I want to have a Horizontal Scale and a Spinbox right next to it that can change each others values. For example, if both go from 1 to 100 and I drag the Scale to 50, I want the number in the spinbox to change to 50 as well and vice versa. This is my attempt at this:

```
class Main_window(ttk.Frame):
    """A program"""
    def __init__(self, master):
    ttk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
    self.grid()
    self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
    """Creates all the objects in the window"""

    self.scale = ttk.Scale(self, orient = HORIZONTAL, length = 200,
                                   from_ = 1.0, to = 100.0,
                                   command = self.update,
                                   ).grid(row = 3,
                                          column = 1,
                                          sticky = W)

    spinval = StringVar()
    self.spinbox = Spinbox(self, from_ = 1.0, to = 100.0,
                                   textvariable = spinval,
                                   command = self.update,
                                   width = 10).grid(row = 3,
                                                    column =3,
                                                    sticky = W)

    def update(self):
        """Changes the spinbox and the scale according to each other"""
        self.scale.set(self.spinbox.get())
        self.spinbox.delete(0.0,END)
        self.spinbox.insert(0.0,self.scale.get())

def main():
    """Loops the window"""
    root = Tk()
    root.title("window")
    root.geometry("400x300")
    app = Main_window(root)
    root.mainloop()

main()
```

First, when I move the scale slider, I get the error:
TypeError: update() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

And second, when I change the value of the spinbox I get:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'set'

I don't know if this is even the right approach to this. Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error *AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'set'* is because you are trying to use the object attributes to store a reference to the widgets, but actually you are storing the result of the calls to `grid`, which is always None. Separate this in two different statements to solve that:

```
self.scale = ttk.Scale(self, ...)
self.scale.grid(...)
# Same for self.spinbox
```

If you want to have the same value for both widgets, then the best alternative is to use the same Tkinter variable:

```
spinval = StringVar()
self.scale = ttk.Scale(self, variable=spinval, ...)
# ...
self.spinbox = Spinbox(self, textvariable = spinval, ...)
```

The problem if you use the same `command` option for both widgets is that they pass a different number of arguments to the function, and also when you set the new value for the other widget it is going to trigger `update` again, so it will end up in an infinite loop of calls to this function.